# Why Symfony2 Validation Constraint is not taken into account?

Tags: validation, symfony, yaml

I have a problem with those validation constraints in Symfony 2.2.

The validation constraints for "username" and "pass" seems not te be taken into account. But the "UniqueEntity" constraints works.

I don't think I made mistake in the yaml syntax.

This is the yml syntax :

```
Fastre\PhpFtpAdminBundle\Entity\Account:
properties:
    username:
        - Regex: {pattern: "/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", message: Le nom d'utilisateur ne peut contenir que des lettres minuscules et majuscules et des chiffres.}
    pass: 
        - Length: {min: 8, minMessage: "Your name must have at least {{ limit }} characters."} 
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: {fields: [username], groups: [registration]}
```

And in the controller :

```
if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {

        $form->bind($request);

        $data = $form->getData();



        $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($data, array('Default'));

        //throw new \Exception($errors->count());

        if ($errors->count() == 0) { //the errors->count() is always set to 0!
            $em->flush();

            //TODO: i18n
            $this->get('session')
                    ->getFlashBag()
                    ->add('notice', 'Compte '.$account->getUsername().' modifié');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('account_list'));

        } else {


            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $this->get('session')
                    ->getFlashBag()
                    ->add('warning', $error->getMessage()); 
            }

            return $this->render('FastrePhpFtpAdminBundle:Accounts:form.html.twig',
                array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'action_path' => $this->generateUrl('account_view', array('id' => $id))
                    )
                );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing this:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($data, array('Default'));
```

You validate only the validation group `Default`. But your `UniqueEntity` constraint applies only on the `registration` group because of your settings:

```
{fields: [username], groups: [registration]}
```

So you can either remove the group for the `UniqueEntity` validation or validate it with a second call like:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($data, array('registration'));
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

On a side note, instead of having:

```
    $form->bind($request);
    $data = $form->getData();
    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($data, array('Default'));
    if ($errors->count() == 0) { 
        //do your stuff
    }
```

I would highly recommend using something more simple:

```
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // do your stuff
    }
```

And for the group validation in this case, please refer to:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups

Comment: You were right. I thought it was existing a "Default" validation group and I thought i used it.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do form validation on validation groups. I think the code '$form->isValid(array('registration'));' will not work. Isn't it ?

Comment: You are right. If you want to do validation group for your form, you have to setup the group in your form type `setDefaultOptions()` or if you don't use form type, in the `createFormBuilder()` call.